# Ubuntu Ethernet not working

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I am new to Linux and used a USB to run Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my new PC. Everything was fine until I checked that the ethernet cable is not working. The PC has no wifi adapter so I can’t use WIFI. I have tried the instructions on:

- https://unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/
- https://medium.com/@lgobinath/no-ethernet-connection-in-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18-with-realtek-rtl8111-8168-8411-7ae2779dc9b8

and also tried to redownload the driver from the Intel site,
but no luck.

Here is some information that might be useful:

```
lsmod | grep e1000
e1000e                245760  0
```

```
dmesg | grep e1000e
[    1.438380] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.438380] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.438542] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.692252] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.763417] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 04:**:f5:**:28:65
[    1.763418] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.763513] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.775740] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   11.825988] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

```
ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::b41b:eaba:945d:2f19  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:d9:f5:87:28:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 243300  bytes 19951408 (19.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 149  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 610  bytes 398215 (398.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xa4300000-a4320000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3497  bytes 305581 (305.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3497  bytes 305581 (305.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
ip route 
*no results*
```

I am using a USB ethernet at the moment and this is working fine (removed the details of this interface for clarity).

Comment: Test the cable first. Most "my ethernet does not work" problems turn out to be a bad (or simply unplugged) cable.

Comment: Yep done this, tried two different cables.

Comment: IP in 172.20.*.* indicates that the machine has acquired an address on a private network, so the Ethernet link is working. Perhaps the connecting setup didn't include routing. What says `ip route` (add answer to your question)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. I have a USB ethernet connected that is working and is what I am using atm.

Comment: Added the ```ip route``` results

Comment: Had to update my results without the USB ethernet.

Comment: Shutdown, remove the cable, reboot, and then plug cable back in.  Sometimes this works.

Comment: I find that sometimes I have to select a disabled ethernet connection in network settings..
    power(windows key) network, select how you connect to the internet.
then select a greyed out tab there.
I dont use wifi so I don't know if that is also supposed to be there.